# Force Firebase to send analytics data upon backgrounding?

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to figure out where users of my app lose interest during the onboarding process. To that end, I've implemented Firebase Analytics. However, it seems that in the scenario where the user only uses the app once never to open it again, the collated analytics data are never uploaded to Firebase. Only when the app is launched a second time, the data are being uploaded.

Does Firebase Analytics have a means of forcing the uploaded upon app backgrounding?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to force the Firebase Analytics client to send its data to the server at any specific time.

But as Todd says in his blog post [How Long Does it Take for My Firebase Analytics Data to Show Up?](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-firebase-analytics-data-to-show-up.html):

> On iOS devices, Firebase will also send down data when your app moves into the background. So if a user tries your app for 20 minutes and then uninstalls it, that session data will still be received, because your app will have sent down the data the moment the user moved your app to the background.

The only caveat to this:

> The one corner case where analytics data would actually get lost on iOS would be if your app crashed and then your user immediately uninstalled it.

So it looks like the analytics data should be sent to the server if the user background the app. If that doesn't happen for you, can you describe the flow of your users whose data is not showing up more explicitly?

Comment: Perfect. Just the article I needed! Thanks, Frank.